# Botão não chama o metodo do web service

Tags: android, onclick

Estou tendo dificuldade em chamar um método do meu webservice,esse método eu mando o boleto por email para o usuário, por algum motivo não está funcionando. Tenho um listview com todos os boletos e o usuário seleciona qual deles ele quer ver os detalhes e nessa activity de detalhes tenho 3 funções que é enviar o boleto por email, enviar linha digitavel do boleto por sms ou somente mostar a linha.

Esse é o metodo de onClick que tenho na activity de detalhes.
está faltando alguma coisa? pois nem os logs eles me mostra.

```
 @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
       switch (v.getId()){

           case R.id.enviaBoletoEmail:
               Log.d("","ENVIANDO BOLETO test 1");

               new Thread(new Runnable() {
                      @Override
                      public void run() {
                          WebService ws = new WebService();
                          Log.d("","ENVIANDO BOLETO teste 2");
                          try {
                              pessoaDao = new PessoaDao(databaseHelper.getConnectionSource());
                              Pessoa pessoa=new Pessoa();
                              pessoa= pessoaDao.queryForId(1);

                              try {
                                  ws.enviarBoletoPDF(sequencia, pessoa.getEmail());

                                  Log.d("","ENVIANDO BOLETO test 3");

                              } catch (IOException e) {
                                  e.printStackTrace();
                              } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
                                  e.printStackTrace();
                              }


                          } catch (SQLException e) {
                              e.printStackTrace();
                          }




                      }
                  }).start();

            break;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui resolver a questão, pesquisando mais o que poderia estar ocasionando meu problema, encontrei sobre boas práticas de como usar os eventos do click.

Ficou da seguinte forma:

```
public View.OnClickListener btnEnviaBoletoPDF = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
             WebService ws = new WebService();

            try {

                pessoaDao = new PessoaDao(databaseHelper.getConnectionSource());
                Pessoa pessoa = new Pessoa();
                pessoa = pessoaDao.queryForId(1);
                Log.d("Sequencia", sequencia);
                ws.enviarBoletoPDF(sequencia,pessoa.getEmail());

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    };
```

*no método onCreate:*

```
enviaBoletoEmail = (Button) findViewById(R.id.enviaBoletoEmail);
enviaBoletoEmail.setOnClickListener(btnEnviaBoletoPDF);
```